# Turning a iteration into a recursion

Tags: java, recursion, int, return, iteration

Good day!

I just wrote a code as an iteration which is supposed to sum up even numbers in between 0 and y.

I've been sitting now on my desk for about two hours thinking on how to write the same code in a recursion - without any progress so far.
The only explanations I find on the internet explain it for one simple repeat of one specific change - unlike my code which includes two. ("result = result + x;" and "x = x + 2;" )
Could someone please explain to me how I turn this kind of iteration into a recursion? Thanks in advance!

```
 public class Sum {

   static int method(int y) { 
     int result = 0; 
     for (int x = 2; x<=y;)
     {
        result = result + x;   
        x = x + 2; 
     }
     return result;
   } 

   public static void main(String[ ] args) {
      int result = method(35); 
      System.out.println("Sum of even numbers between 0-35: " +result); 
   }
}
```

Comment: you don't even need iteration or recursion. Just need a mathematical formula to calculate this sum.

Answer (score 2):

The total of the numbers is the total of this number plus the total of the number minus 2. Written in code:

```
int method(int y) { 
  if (y <= 0) {
     return 0;
  } else {
     return y + method(y - 2);
  }
}
```

Needless to say that recursion in this form is not necessary, and will create a `StackoverflowException` when `y` is a really large number. Some languages allow you to write a recursive function and indicate it is a [tail recursion](https://www.scala-exercises.org/scala_tutorial/tail_recursion) so that the compiler actually transforms it to an iteration.